# C++ Idiomatic Type Traits

Tags: c++, type-traits

I have a system of type traits that resides in a namespace, like so:

```
namespace my_namespace
{

template <typename T>
struct magic_traits
{
    static const int value = 0;
};

}
```

Because people hate the syntax of template specializations, I have this convenient little macro:

```
#define DECLARE_MY_MAGIC_TRAITS(type_, value_) \
    namespace my_namespace                     \
    {                                          \
        template <>                            \
        struct magic_traits<type_ > {          \
            static const int value = value_;   \
        };                                     \
    }

}
```

My problem is that this only works for declarations made in the global namespace, so traits for a type in some other namespace looks like this:

```
DECLARE_MAGIC_TRAITS(other_namespace::some_type, 9)
```

That's great, if people know about all the little namespace rules about where `DECLARE_MAGIC_TRAITS` belongs.  If they don't and put the declaration in their own namespace, they'll get errors like:

```
'magic_traits' is not a template!
Specialization of non-template 'other_namespace::my_namespace::magic_traits'
```

Which are quite confusing to a new user of your library!

**Is there a way to make that macro be able to define a specialization of `magic_traits` from anywhere?**  If that is not possible (as I suspect): **What techniques can be used to generate more reasonable error messages?**

I should note that my users are mostly Python programmers and have very little C++ experience, so anything I can do to make their lives easier, the better.

Comment: If they're writing C++, the best thing you can do to make their lives easier, is make them learn C++.

Comment: You want a macro that does "closes all open namespaces, do stuff, and reopen all the namespaces"?

Comment: @Martinho: Indeed.  But you have to learn an awful lot of C++ to understand WTF type traits do, and what the corresponding syntax means!

Comment: @Oli: But typically you shouldn't be required to _define_ new type traits unless you were fairly familiar with your project and the language -- tangential users shouldn't need to have to add traits, I suppose.

Comment: @Oli: I honestly don't think it is better to have them use type traits without knowing WTF they are.

Comment: Perhaps I'm traveling too far down the "make it *really* easy" path...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Maybe a bit ugly, but how about this as an idea :

```
namespace my_namespace
{

typedef bool The_DECLARE_MY_MAGIC_TRAITS_macro_should_be_used_in_the_global_namespace;

template <typename T>
struct magic_traits
{
    static const int value = 0;
};

}

#define DECLARE_MY_MAGIC_TRAITS(type_, value_) \
    namespace my_namespace {                   \
        typedef The_DECLARE_MY_MAGIC_TRAITS_macro_should_be_used_in_the_global_namespace CheckPrecondition; \
        template <>                            \
        struct magic_traits<type_ > {          \
            static const int value = value_;   \
        };                                     \
    }
```

When the macro is used incorrectly, it would generate an error such as this :

```
error: ‘The_DECLARE_MY_MAGIC_TRAITS_macro_should_be_used_in_the_global_namespace’ does not name a type
error: ‘magic_traits’ is not a template
error: explicit specialization of non-template ‘other_namespace::my_namespace::magic_traits’
```

That might give enough of a hint as to what's wrong.

Comment: The problem here is the multiple declaration issue: `CheckPrecondition` will already be defined if there is more than one `DECLARE_MY_MAGIC_TRAITS` in a single compilation unit.  This can be worked around with some `BOOST_PP_COUNTER` magic.

Comment: @Travis : maybe I'm misunderstanding you, but unlike in C, in C++ it's perfectly valid to have the same typedef appear more than once in the same scope. Or to say it with the words of the standard : __In a given non-class scope, a typedef specifier can be used to redefine the name of any type declared in
that scope to refer to the type to which it already refers.__

Comment: Haha, you're right. Stupid switching between multiple languages gets me all messed up.

Comment: @Travis : Not sure if I'd actually use this suggested approach in production code though ... it's a nice "trick" for template meta programming, but maybe it should stay in that niche heh. I agree with what others have mentioned that education of the users is probably the way to go (either through documentation, a C++ course, ...)

Answer (score 1):

There is probaly nothing better than good documentation.

You should tell the users of your DECLARE_MAGIC_TRAITS macro where to put the macro, and what to write inside the parameters (with examples)

And make the error messages a faq entry so that users will find a good answer to what went wrong.